# Manifolds - Defining a chart on a parametrised curve

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I've been given a question in preparation for an exam and just cant seem to get my head around it. I will include my attempt below.

**The Question**

Let $\gamma(t) = (t,t^2)$ be a parametrised curve in the (x,y)-plane of $\mathbb{R}^3$, where $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Consider the set $\Sigma$ that is swept by $\gamma$ when it translates along the vector $v=(1,0,1)$, that is, $\Sigma$ is formed by all the lines $l_{p,v} = \{p+sv, s \in \mathbb{R}\}$, where p ranges over the image of $\gamma$. Construct a chart on $\Sigma$ and verify that your answer satisfies the conditions for a regular surface.

**My attempt**

So the way I have attempted to attack this is essentially a sketch where I think that $\Sigma$ is actually just a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is just essentially moved up 1 in the z-direction, I didn't think that the translation of +1 in the x-direction mattered since $\gamma$ technically only cares about its x,y coordinates being that it "lives" in the (x,y,1)-plane. With that in mind, now all that is left to do is to define the chart $(U,\varphi)$, so I took $U =(x,y,1)$ plane and $\varphi : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ means that I want to be able to define a map $\varphi$ that maps $U$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Hence I set
$$
\varphi(x,y,z) \rightarrow (r,\theta,1) \implies (x,y,z) \rightarrow (r\sin(\theta),r\cos(\theta), 1)$$
The polar coordinates where $r=\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $\theta= \tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$. In order for this chart to show that $\Sigma$ is in fact a 2-dimensional regular surface, this would mean that $\varphi$ needs to map the entirety of $\Sigma$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$, I.e., $\varphi(\Sigma) \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. Now because of this, I note that I can differentiate $\varphi$ so this means that it is smooth and there is also an inverse $\varphi^{-1}$ which would just simply reverse the map and go back to polar coordinates.

Comment: I am not completely sure I understood all those "esentially", but $\Sigma$ is not a plane. Have you tried some drawing?

Comment: You are totally wrong. The surface a cylindrical fence over the parabola, with the fenceposts all lines parallel to $v$.

Comment: @TedShifrin So $\Sigma$ is a kind of tube-like structure over $\gamma$? I dont understand what you mean by fencepost all lines parallel to v?

Comment: Hi @TedShifrin Just out curiousity since $\Sigma$ is this tube structure then would the best way to show this is infact a regular surface would be via the regular value theorem and using level sets?

Comment: Where are you getting the word tube?

Comment: @TedShifrin I didnt understand what you mean by Cylindrical fence, would this imply that   surface like wraps around the curve $\gamma$ and then unbounded below that surface if you get what I mean, I'll try include a picture of what I intepret as a cylindrical fence

Comment: It is the simplest sort of ruled surface. The problem tells you how to parametrize the surface explicitly with $s$ and $t$.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/LjYsysa.png

Comment: Oh so would I use something like $\Phi (t,s) : \gamma (t) + vs $?

Comment: As like the map for my chart and then go about showing showing the differential via the jacobian of $\Phi$ doesnt vanish so it would satisfy the definition of a chart of a surface?